# grouping or bundling of notifications in iOS inbox style notification

Tags: ios, push-notification, notifications, grouping

In My App I am using firebase push notification. Problem is when user connected to internet after long time they will receive lot of notifications as individual notification. Is it Possible to Receive Notification like whatsapp(You have 10 New Notification). Inbox style Notification like android

Comment: There's no such things in iOS

Comment: Thanks but are you sure i got one link explaining about thread_id usage for grouping of messages and for that one has to make changes in UNnotificationContentExtension for changing UI of push notifications to group them under one title.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple notifications with the same collapse identifier are displayed to the user as a single notification. This can be handled from server side not at client side. APNS header **apns-collapse-id** will be used to update previously sent notification.

Refer to this for further description:

[Table 8-2APNs request headers](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH11-SW13)

[Apple Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html)